# Spring Redis custom OidcUser session sharing

Tags: session, spring-security, redis, openid-connect, okta

We have integration with Okta and use Redis for storing user sessions. However, when obtaining an OidcUser, we modify their roles by returning a custom implementation class. Our goal is to share the session across multiple applications. On the main application where the CustomOidcUser is created, everything works as expected. But on another application, we get a ClassNotFoundException.

Please advise on how to configure security so that the user can be recognized as a regular OidcUser in other applications?

Answer (score 0):

as possible solution -> you can create DefaultOidcUser instead of using custom one

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).